# User views on Data Explorer is wrong or extremely out-of-date

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, views

I noticed that the `Users.Views` field for every single active user is extremely out of date. It is even zero/missing for some (not too new) users.

[image]

**Example:**

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110401/user-profile-views?UserId=335858
https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight

This user's account is almost 3 years old, yet...

His profile shows 10k views. The DE shows 0.

**Another Example:**

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110401/user-profile-views?UserId=505088
https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan

- Profile Views: 23k
- Data Explorer Views: 1284

---

Did I get the query wrong? Or have user views on the Data Explorer not been updated in years?

Comment: Mine says 344. Oh, and 7 on Meta! Ding ding ding, winner!

Comment: Running it on myself shows 0. ahaha

Comment: I've just ran into this bug myself. Just now, it shows that our [Thomas Pornin](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) has 22 views. Pretty strange.

Comment: FWIW my query for the Least Viewed Questions (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116139/least-viewed-questions) also demonstrates out of date behaviour. For example, questions which appear as having 1 or 2 views actually have 42.

Comment: @DanielDaranas That one is different. The DE is only updated once a week. But profile views haven't been updated in years.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some form of script that does what DE does? Sounds like Profile Views is a manually run script that has been lost to the ages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this has been broken ever since we moved ViewCount to another table for both Users and Posts (to relieve some update contention and tangential reasons).

Good news is that makes it an easy fix, it will be corrected when on the next data refresh - when the job runs again this Sunday.

Comment: Was the search mechanism affected by this as well? If so the fix might apply to [those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185795/152859) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184742/152859) bugs too. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd they are tangentially related, separate issue with how indexing works though

Comment: Cheers Nick, so you're looking into the search related issues?