# How to find the user or developer with the highest number of profile views?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

Can you please tell me how to find the user or developer that has the highest number of profile views?

Comment: Didn't look, but I can pretty much guarantee that on Stack Overflow that is Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, that i know but may be he is base on reputation but i want to check out base on profile view :)

Comment: Um. Yes. Also that.

Comment: @chintankhetiya There's a pretty strong correlation between reputation and profile views, I imagine.

Comment: Jon Skeet is answer to "who is the user with the most/highest/maximum X" questions, for great many X values.

Comment: Don't you think that my question is also deserve for up votes.

Comment: Not... really... I don't see the significance in having the most profile views out of any user.

Comment: Last time I looked, Jon Skeet had as many profile views as reputation points.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not in every highest X. E.g. downvotes, review etc.. :)

Comment: @hims056 yeah, though if he'll focus his attention on reviews he'll reach the top before we can say "Jon Skeet". :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go with [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116073/top-100-highest-profile-views)

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Views DESC) AS Rank
              , ID AS [User Link]
              , Views, Reputation, Location 
FROM USERS
```

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Rank  ║      User       ║    Views  ║  Reputation  ║        Location         ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║     1 ║ Jon Skeet       ║    639947 ║       610427 ║ Reading, United Kingdom ║
║     2 ║ Eric Lippert    ║    176837 ║       249482 ║ Seattle, WA             ║
║     3 ║ Marc Gravell    ║    133054 ║       423970 ║ Forest of Dean, UK      ║
║     4 ║ Jeff Atwood     ║    122506 ║        27684 ║ El Cerrito, CA          ║
║     5 ║ BalusC          ║    115142 ║       425228 ║ Willemstad, Curaçao     ║
║     6 ║ Darin Dimitrov  ║    106748 ║       466354 ║ Sofia, Bulgaria         ║
║     7 ║ Bill the Lizard ║     82214 ║       124132 ║ Charlotte, NC           ║
║     8 ║ Hans Passant    ║     80089 ║       389208 ║ Madison, WI             ║
║     9 ║ CommonsWare     ║     75888 ║       322395 ║ Where You Least Expect  ║
║    10 ║ casperOne       ║     62554 ║        45832 ║ Brooklyn, NY            ║
║   ... ║                 ║           ║              ║                         ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Amazing how outdated the data is, 559,060 views live vs. "only" 195,496 in the data explorer. Oh, there is [open bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178152/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah thanks for [adding a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178152/187824)

Comment: That was back when Rich B was one of the most well-known users. He's 17th according to the Data Explorer and he might have had the most profile views of anyone (save possibly Jeff Atwood) at one point.

Comment: It must however be highlighted that there are users who have very likely gamed the system to obtain their profile views according to the analysis that I have carried out at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376361/how-to-find-the-sample-points-that-have-statistically-meaningful-large-outlier-r

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/115923) for this. At the time of writing, here's the top 10:

```
Id    Reputation DisplayName            Views  

----- ---------- ---------------------- ------ 

22656 566017     Jon Skeet              195496 
23354 392057     Marc Gravell           49421  
1     25815      Jeff Atwood            41072  
88656 224983     Eric Lippert           36676  
4     19569      Joel Spolsky           32408  
95810 260640     Alex Martelli          26717  
18393 218278     cletus                 23156  
34509 202424     Johannes Schaub - litb 19393  
33708 162443     Mehrdad Afshari        19160  
1288  112464     Bill the Lizard        18229
```

Comment: These counts are awfully low, actually. I'd be in 8th place according to my profile counter..

Comment: Did not realize how far behind that is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [yep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178152/152859). :/

Answer (score 6):

I believe [the property you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is `static readonly`.

Comment: There is an interesting competiting between his reputation and profile views.

Comment: yeah ,that was the reason behind to ask :)