# "Notable questions" badge page and search report different numbers for questions with 2.5K views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, search, views

On Travel-SE, there are currently [171 "Notable question" badges](https://travel.stackexchange.com/badges/27/notable-question) awarded. However, when one uses the search interface with `views:2500`, [there are 106 results](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A2500). The two numbers should be equal, and it's difficult to explain the difference with caching issues.

As the number of views is ever-increasing (as we all know, it's impossible to un-see things, unfortunately), this seems like a bug. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Also, some questions which should qualify don't appear on the search page. See [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa), for example.

None of these questions are closed or deleted: `views:2500 closed:yes` and `views:2500 deleted:yes` return 0 results.

Eeeek?

Comment: Have you accounted for deleted and migrated questions? Don't forget - badges awarded due to such questions are not going to be taken away.

Comment: shouldn't be that many deleted/migrated NOTABLE questions...

Comment: @Oded: we have 12 migrated questions total, none of which are even close

Comment: @Oded The example question above is shown in the badges page but not in the search page..

Comment: I would take a guess that the search is looking on a view count in different table and that view count wasn't updated for LONG time. Adding relevant tag in case I'm correct and it's bug in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the search index is only updated once any other activity happens on a post (for example, a vote).

Thus, the views reported by the search engine are always less than or equal to the real views, and therefore the result you are getting is not unexpected.