# Views are not updated in search when a question was migrated

Tags: bug, search, views, migrated-questions

If I search for `views:1..1`, I get numerous results. Most of them have far more views than just one, however. Like 27 views sometimes.

You might assume caching causes newer questions to stay in the list, but none of the results are new at all (well, some may be new, but not most). I get a lot of stuff from 2015, for example.

While [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184742) would explain some of the results, it utterly fails to account for questions like this one: [Getting segmentation fault when giving input to structure members on run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644081). It has a number of views in addition to *two answers* (one of which is a self answer). Or this question: [How do I get scripts running again if the AppsScript service has been throttled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706061) which has four up votes.

I didn't see the connection when I first asked this question, but these questions were all migrated from another site.

---

Here are searches for three big sites, which have enough migrations that just slip through the cracks:

[Search on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=views%3A1..1)

[Search on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=views%3A1..1)

[Search on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3a1..1)

It's a bit sad to know that numerous questions were migrated just to be ignored on another site...

Comment: "The reason is that the search index is only updated once any other activity happens on a post (for example, a vote)."

Comment: @hichris123 The question actually feels vaguely familiar to me. But it doesn't help me to find questions that legitimately only have *x* views.

Comment: Well, you really can't. SEDE should help a bit, but obviously those numbers will be off a bit (more depending on how late in the week it is).

Comment: @hichris123 Some of the questions have up votes and answers. This is a possible bug with migration.