# Most viewed question does not appear in search when restrained by number of views

Tags: bug, search, views

[This question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2675/49) is currently the one with the highest views (2000+) at [Anime & Manga SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com).

However, when I [search for questions with over 1000 views](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+views%3A1000), it does not appear.
This was happening even before it was the highest viewed question.

---

**EDIT**

Here's another case where it happens, this time at [Music SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/).
[This question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/yamaha-vs-casio-digital-piano-is-there-an-objective-comparison), with over 10000 views, does not appear in [search for questions with over 10000 views](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A10000+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Looks like the view counter related to search stopped working several months ago, see [this related report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184742/152859).